# How to make a nickname Changes History Command | Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wonder if there is any way to make a command that shows all Nickname changes in a certain server like shown below with Blargbot

[image: Blargbot "names" command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that they're using some kind of DB to store the nicknames (SQLite, MongoDB, Postgres etc.). You can catch the user changing their nickname with the `on_member_update` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(old, new):
    if old.nick != new.nick and new.nick:
        # store new.nick in a database
```

`old.nick != new.nick` is making sure that it's the nickname that changed, and not something else (such as their status or roles).
`and new.nick` is making sure that their new nickname exists (`!= None`). Having the first condition is not enough, because this event will also fire if the user removes their nickname, and you want to make sure that it isn't `None`. Although if you do want to store when they remove their nicknames, then you can just stick to the first condition.

---

**References:**

- [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)
- [`Member.nick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.nick)